# Установка нескольких модулей nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm

Всем привет!
Возникла проблема -- после установки модуля последующие модуля не устанавливаются и пишет ошибку

> 'Cannot find module 'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js''

Как это решить?
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Какой модуль Вы установили, после которого появилась эта ошибка?

Comment: Ставил uws -- появилась такая ошибка. Потом поставил steam-market-pricing -- ошибка. Сделал наоборот -- то же самое

Answer (score 0):

Вот ответ на ваш вопрос.
Проблема связана с неправильным путем узла в системной переменной

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24741740/17150092